# Is it Possible to Save Images to Documents Directory Android Studio - Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, relative-path

I am creating an app in which a .pdf file is generated and stored in the documents directory. The app also prompts the user for images and I would like to save them in the same location as the .pdf but from what I have gathered, it seems images can only be stored in the pictures directory.

From RELATIVE_PATH documentation, "...content must be placed under a top-level directory that is relevant to the media type. For example, attempting to place a audio/mpeg file under Environment#DIRECTORY_PICTURES will be rejected."

This seems crazy to me and like there has to be a workaround but I can't figure it out. Has anyone else dealt with this and are able to provide a solution?

Comment: You can save any file in Documents directory. Image and audio files too. Any.

Comment: You cannot create an audio file in the Pictures directory as it is not a picture. Instead write audio files to Music directory. Also you cannot create image files in Music. It is as simple as that. There is also a story about video files.

Comment: Im puzzled why you just did not try..

Comment: `From RELATIVE_PATH documentation, "` Aha... You are using the MediaStore. Well then you can. But at the moment i dont have that code at hand.